# SSD with 8K blocksize on Linux

Tags: linux

I have a SSD drive that uses 8K block size. On x86_64 Linux, ext4/xfs won't support blocksize larger than Linux PAGE_SIZE, which is 4K.

I have tried using LVM and mdadm RAID0 with stripping set to 8K hoping that the drive will be sent 8K sizeed IO requests, but unfortunately all IO requests are 4K only.

How can I can setup the drive in such a way that the file system is 4K based (to keep ext4/xfs happy) but the requests sent to the drive are 8K?

Or is there some code that I can write to make this happen? Perhaps play around with /dev/mapper? I'm open to ideas and suggestions.

The SSD drive I'm using is an eval unit that has not been released yet. Works under Windows, being tested on Linux.

TIA

Comment: Add the make/model of SSD to your question.

Comment: You can't format comments. You can edit your question (preferred over comments; comments may not stick around), and format properly in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using LVM anda stripe width. Rather than try to explain it in my own words, there's a very good write up on the problem similar to yours, how to partition the disk, format it with the correct stripe, etc.

https://thunk.org/tytso/blog/2009/02/20/aligning-filesystems-to-an-ssds-erase-block-size/

Would be interesting to see benchmarks before and after using this method.

Comment: Thank you. After reading the article I ran the following commands but I still get  only 4K accesses to the SSD device.  
    1. fdisk -H 224 -S 56 /dev/nvme0n1  
    2. pvcreate /dev/nvme0n1p1  
    3. vgcreate  --metadatasize 250k nvmedisk /dev/nvme0n1p1  
    4. lvcreate -l 100%FREE --name n1 nvmedisk  
    5. mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard,stripe-width=32 /dev/nvmedisk/n1  
I also tried the above commands using stripe-width=2

Comment: sorry, I was unable to format my comment. I tried using two spaces at the end of each line and also 4 spaces before each line but neither of them managed to format my reply

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  When all of the meat of an answer is in an external link, the answer can become useless if the link breaks.  Even while the link is good, readers need to go somewhere else for the solution.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post a helpful link in a comment.  For an answer post, please include the essential information within the answer, and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.